# Got warning after update angular 7 to angular 8 version

Tags: css, angular

I updated the packages and after starting npm i got 2 warning which are follows:

> WARNING in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--13-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
>   Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   Warning
>
> (5013:3) end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
>
> WARNING in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--13-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
>   Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   Warning
>
> (5019:3) end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

Answer (score 27):

This warning is saying that you should  use `flex-start` instead of `start.` Same for `flex-end`.
And this is just a warning, it won't affect your project.

Answer (score 2):

This error generally comes in SCSS/CSS file. In your stylesheet just search "start" and replace it with flex-start. This property is used to justify-content in the navbar etc.