# Angular CLI: ng build warning in TFS Build step

Tags: azure-devops, angular-cli, angular9, azure-devops-server-2019

I have an angular project that I am trying to build though Azure DevOps. When I run the ng build on a library project, there are some warnings

> ex(##[error]WARNING: autoprefixer: D:\Agent_work\1\s\Test\projects\test-library\src\components\test.component.css:4:5: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead)

The build step fails because of this. the command for this step is "ng build test-library"

Is there a way in TFS or a setting on ng build to ignore these warnings?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

Please add `continueOnError` to your task:

```yaml
- task: string  # reference to a task and version, e.g. "VSBuild@1"
  condition: expression     # see below
  continueOnError: boolean  # 'true' if future steps should run even if this step fails; defaults to 'false'
  enabled: boolean          # whether or not to run this step; defaults to 'true'
  timeoutInMinutes: number  # how long to wait before timing out the task
  target: string            # 'host' or the name of a container resource to target
```

or here if you use classic pipelines:
[image]

[However I would recommend you to get rid of this warning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471378/got-warning-after-update-angular-7-to-angular-8-version)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change `justify-content: start` property to `justify-content: flex-start`.

[image]

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp).